# Omnipay - How do I pass 'custom' or 'invoice' parameters to Paypal?

Tags: paypal, omnipay

In the past I have used html forms to pass hidden 'custom' and 'invoice' parameters to Paypal during Credit Card transactions, using Paypal-Pro, so that I can use them in the IPN response later. However I can't seem to work out how to set/send these two parameters using Omnipay. If anyone could point me in the right direction here it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See duplicate posting:

https://github.com/omnipay/paypal/issues/10

You can use:

```
$request->setTransactionId();
$request->setDescription();
```

or

```
$data = $request->getData();
$data['RANDOM_DATA'] = 'hello';
$request->sendData($data);
```

instead of simply calling `$request->send()`.

Comment: Second part isn't working, do we still need to call $request->send() and moreover how to receive data